404 not found while using Axios and useQuery tanstack
API response, here is my function where I get the information from mysql and the database is working fine, because when I use the Post function in Insomnia I am getting the response:
export const getCourses = (req, res) => {
  const q = `SELECT c.*, u.id AS teacherId FROM courses AS c JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = c.teacherId)`;

  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    return res.status(200).json(data);
  });
};

Axios request function:
export const makeRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8800/api/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: [{ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin, "access-control-allow-credentials": true }],
  method: "GET",
  url: "requisitions",
});

Front-end request (useQuery):
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["courses"],
  queryFn: () => makeRequest
    .get("/courses")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    }),
});

Main backend file, where I import express. It listens to the port 8800: index.js:
    import express from "express";
    
    import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
    import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
    import courseRoutes from "./routes/courses.js";
    
    import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
    import cors from "cors";
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", methods: ["GET", "POST"], credentials: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
    app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
    app.use("/api/courses", courseRoutes);
    
    app.listen(8800, () => {
      console.log("API connected");
    });

Can you please provide a proper example of how you connect your api using express and axios? Maybe I will compare them and it will help?.
The error I am getting: GET http://localhost:8800/api/courses 404 (Not Found)
I tried to POST using Insomnia and I got the response. But here I am getting the error.
How can I solve this error?

Hello Tadashi, can you be more specific about your backend, I guess you are using Express, but is it correct? if it is, can you please share your express index.js file or you main file, please?

for what route is API response: the response code?

Provide a code of your request handler app.get('/api/courses',(req,res) =>{...})

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@ヴァルガスアルド Hey, I've edited the answer. Please check to see the index.js code.

@JaromandaX it is: http://localhost:8800/api/courses/

Why do I get the information when I use Insomnia, and I didn't use the Get function, I used POST and I am receiving the information on my preview panel. Is that ok? why so many access protocols if I can just access the information using Insomnia? (Sorry, I am new to this)

and what does routes/courses.js look like - I didn't use the Get function, I used POST that's what showing that file will determine

@JaromandaX OMG! You were right! The code was "router.post("/", getCourses);"  I changed it to "router.get("/", getCourses);" I am so glad! It was so stupid of me to make such an obvious mistake!

Fix your request handler like this for example
 app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
      const q = `SELECT c.*, u.id AS teacherId FROM courses AS c JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = c.teacherId)`;
    
      db.query(q, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        return res.json(data);
      });
    });


it didn't help. Same error

What port does your express app listen ? Provide more code please

It listens to 3000 (my client port) and my api port is (8800).

What code do you need? Thank you for responding
